# Regexp to match either string, either int

Tags: php, regex

suppose we have the following string :

```
$a = 'a == 1';
$b = 'b == "1"';
$c = "c == '1'";
$d = "d == 'd'";
```

I would like to match using regexp the number/element in quote, in the following case :

- If we don't have (single or double) quotes, we can match only (positive) number with digit
- If we have quotes, we match all in quotes.

Actually, my regexp is

```
((?<guillemet>"|\')(?<valeur>.*?)(\k<guillemet>)|(?<valeur_numerique>\d+))
```

So I get in my  result array three keys : 'guillemet', 'valeur_numerique' and 'valeur'. For example for `$a`, I get

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  'guillemet' => '',
  1 => '',
  'valeur' => '',
  2 => '',
  3 => '',
  'valeur_numerique' => '1',
  4 => '1',
)
```

Should it be possible to simplify the regexp, in order to have directly `valeur`, without preoccuping of quote? That is, for $a, to get

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '',
  'valeur' => '1',
  2 => '',
  3 => '',
  4 => '1',
)
```

Without having to write myself any kind of filtering.

Comment: Unable to understand connection between input parameters you shown and what actually you have asked at the end of your question

Comment: It depends much on your input. If the strings are standalone and are like that, you may try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/4KdXfx/2), something like `(?<guillemet>["\'])(?<valeur>(?:(?!\k<guillemet>)\D)*)(\k<guillemet>)|(?<valeur_numerique>\d+)`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have change my text, to be more clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. I looked on your regex. For, In my example $a, $b, $c etc, was note part of the value to be test. What I need is to test $a, $b, $c (preg_match('myregepx', $a). And with your regex, I still have three items in my array.

Comment: If you defined three groups you will always have them in the output. You may simply remove the empty ones with `array_filter`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my question was explicitly : how to simplify my regexp to not have to define three groups...

Comment: There is one problem: you want to make sure the quotes match, and thus you need a capturing group. Once the group is defined, and it matches, it will be part  of the resulting array. Well, I believe you want something like [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/4KdXfx/3), see the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/TLSdS).

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to press it all into one (sub)pattern. It is easier to define alternatives. I normally would unquote the value separately, but it is possible using the `J` (PCRE2_DUPNAMES) modifier. It allows for duplicate group names.

```
$pattern = '(
  (?<literal>                
    (?:"(?<value>[^"]*)")|    # double quoted value
    (?:\'(?<value>[^\']*)\')| # single quoted value
    (?:(?<value>[+-]?\d+))    # signed integer
  )
)xJ';
    
$examples = [
    'a == 1', 'b == "1"', "c == '1'", "d == 'd'", "some == other"
];

foreach ($examples as $example) {
    echo $example, "\n";
    if (preg_match($pattern, $example, $match)) {
        echo json_encode(
            array_filter($match, fn($key) => is_string($key), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY),
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        ), "\n";
    } else {
        echo "NO_MATCH\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a == 1
{
    "literal": "1",
    "value": "1"
}
b == "1"
{
    "literal": "\"1\"",
    "value": "1"
}
c == '1'
{
    "literal": "'1'",
    "value": "1"
}
d == 'd'
{
    "literal": "'d'",
    "value": "d"
}
some == other
NO_MATCH
```

Comment: Thanks. The main reason of my question was to avoid to filter my output _a posteriori_. So your answer don't get the point, as it's require I filter the quotes.

Comment: Updated the answer to capture the value without quotes.

Comment: Thanks ! that is nice.